# Number of square ($0$, $1$)-matrices with $1$s confined to main diagonal & contiguous sub & superdiagonals with column and row sums in {$0$, $1$}

Tags: combinatorics, matrices

What is the number of n x n $(0,1)$-matrices having exactly k $1$s ($0$ $\leq$ k $\leq$ n), with the $1$s confined to the main diagonal, plus the first m<sub>d</sub> subdiagonals, plus the first m<sub>u</sub> superdiagonals ($0$ $\leq$ m<sub>d</sub>,m<sub>u</sub> $\lt$ n), such that the column and row sums are all either $0$ or $1$?

Comment: Looks like this is essentially the same as [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/545200/there-are-12-stations-between-a-and-b-in-how-many-ways-you-can-select-4-stati/545210#545210), and [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/153030/counting-train-stops-using-combinatorics).

Comment: Yes; I agree they're equivalent. As no-one has answered this question yet, I will generalize it so it's different.